# Object passed as parameters as if we are passing constructor values

Tags: c++, object, parameters, constructor

I was studying Object composition when I came across the below code on learncpp.com...all definition are in .h file only to make the code concise.

The question is : In main.cpp file when Creature object is initialised, right paratmer {4,7} (which I think invokes the constructor of Point2D) is passed instead of object...How does that work and why ?

Also if instead of {4,7} if (4,7) is passed I get an error as parameter mismatch...why ?

Thnx in advance.

Point2D.h:

```
#ifndef POINT2D_H
#define POINT2D_H

#include <iostream>

class Point2D
{
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;

public:
    // A default constructor
    Point2D()
        : m_x{ 0 }, m_y{ 0 }
    {
    }

    // A specific constructor
    Point2D(int x, int y)
        : m_x{ x }, m_y{ y }
    {
    }

    // An overloaded output operator
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point2D &point)
    {
        out << '(' << point.m_x << ", " << point.m_y << ')';
        return out;
    }

    // Access functions
    void setPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

};

#endif
```

Creature.h:

```
#ifndef CREATURE_H
#define CREATURE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Point2D.h"

class Creature
{
private:
    std::string m_name;
    Point2D m_location;

public:
    Creature(const std::string &name, const Point2D &location)
        : m_name{ name }, m_location{ location }
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Creature &creature)
    {
        out << creature.m_name << " is at " << creature.m_location;
        return out;
    }

    void moveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        m_location.setPoint(x, y);
    }
};
#endif
```

Main.cpp:

````
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Creature.h"
#include "Point2D.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a name for your creature: ";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    Creature creature{ name, { 4, 7 }; 
// Above {4,7} is passed instead of an object

    while (true)
    {
        // print the creature's name and location
        std::cout << creature << '\n';

        std::cout << "Enter new X location for creature (-1 to quit): ";
        int x{ 0 };
        std::cin >> x;
        if (x == -1)
            break;

        std::cout << "Enter new Y location for creature (-1 to quit): ";
        int y{ 0 };
        std::cin >> y;
        if (y == -1)
            break;

        creature.moveTo(x, y);
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: In that context `(4,7)` is a parenthesized [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) with the result `7`. In the context, the one with the curly-braces `{ 4, 7 }` means an object of the `Point2D` type.

Comment: `Creature creature{ name, { 4, 7 }; ` this code won't compile, you have a braces mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11).

Given `Creature creature{ name, { 4, 7 } };`, as the effect, a temporary `Point2D` is constructed from the braced-init-list `{ 4, 7 }` by the constructor `Point2D::Point2D(int, int)`. Then the temporary is passed to the constructor of `Creature`.

As [@Someprogrammerdude's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911356/object-passed-as-parameters-as-if-we-are-passing-constructor-values/61911421#comment109502748_61911356) explained, `(4,7)` doesn't work this way. It's a [comma operator expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) which just returns the 2nd operand. You might specify the temporary explicitly like `Creature creature{ name, Point2D( 4, 7 ) };`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this:

```
Creature creature{ name, { 4, 7 }};
```

The `{4, 7}` part is determined to be of type `Point2D` and constructed using copy-list-initialization. When you use `(4, 7)` this is is the comma operator wrapped in brackets. It results in the value `7` and cannot be used to initialize a `Point2D`.